# Loop for onmousemove event

Tags: javascript

I've run into a problem with running a loop to trigger a `mousemove` event on my HTML/CSS.

I know I can go through and get every individual ID on the HTML tags to execute the code the way I want. But I know there is a better way to do it with a loop of some sort and use far less code.

The images should follow the mouse while moving over the `div` with class `mycard`. Any suggestions or ideas on how to get it working properly would be very much appreciated.

I've tried running a loop to add the classes to `div`s but had no luck.

```js
var mouseHover = document.getElementById('moveHover');

window.onmousemove = function(e) {

  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  mouseHover.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
  mouseHover.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

```css
.mycard span {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}

.mycard:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgHover a {
  position: relative;
}

.imgHover span {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}

.imgHover a:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgHover mycard">
  <div class="cardcost">
    <p class="cardcosttext">2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hscardepic">
    <a style="margin-left: 1000%;vertical-align: middle;">
      Doomsayer
      <span id="moveHover">
        <img src="Classic_Set/doomsayer.png" height="300" width="300" /> 
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="cardamount">
    <p class="cardamounttext">&times;2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what about this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you could use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the elements and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to move them:

```
// get the div that responds to mouse movement
const mycard = document.querySelector('.mycard');

// add a mousemove listener
mycard.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // get the DOM element with the mousemove listener from the event
  const {target} = e;

  // get img child elements of the target.
  // (use whatever css selector you need here. doesn't have to img)
  const images = target.querySelectorAll('img');

  // iterate over each item...
  images.forEach(image => {
    // ...and do whatever you need to do with it
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;
    image.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    image.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand what your code is doing and it works very well for the first div.I changed the querySelectorAll to span to display the image. Unfortunately it only displays the first divs hidden image. I have other mycard divs that follow the first one, and it is not applying to them.

Comment: If you need this on more than one element, you could either put the listener on `window` instead and then check the target to see if it's one you care about, or change the first `querySelector` call to `querySelectorAll` and add the listener to each instance.

Comment: Problem solved, I put the listener on window and it works perfectly. Thank you so much, I was so close so many times... I am very impressed especially since I left out alot of my css to even be able to run the snippet properly. In the future I will try to be more concise with my problem and end goal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not entirely sure what your end-goal is, but I'll take a stab at it.

I would recommend changing `moveHover` to being the class instead of the ID. Then you could do something like this:

```
var mouseHover = null;

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  if(mouseHover != null){
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    mouseHover.style.top = (y+20) + 'px';
    mouseHover.style.left = (x+20) + 'px';
  }
};

function onHover(e){
  mouseHover = e.target.querySelector('.moveHover');
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('imgHover');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].onmouseenter = onHover;
}
```

The loop runs one time to set the `onmouseenter` event. Sure beats moving all `.moveHover` elements all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Had the previous commenter's code not worked I would've attempted to use yours more thoroughly. I will work on explaining my end goal for the code I have problems with.